# Sorting parent based on child's attribute value

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML which comes with itemid embedded as the child's attribute. I am supposed to sort the XML based on the value of ItemID. Here is the XML

```
    <MultiApi TransIdKey="e5d6bd63-88cd-455f-8ab3-9510b5edb2b7" OrderId="" SoId="">
    <API FlowName="Reservation"> 
        <Input>
            <ReserveItemInventory CheckInventory="Y" DemandType="RESERVED" ItemID="19998548" OrganizationCode="" QtyToBeCancelled="0" QtyToBeReserved="1" ReservationID="1000000000003" ShipNode="DC-W" UnitOfMeasure="EACH" xmlns="http://www.sterlingcommerce.com/documentation/YFS/reserveItemInventory/input"/>
        </Input>
    </API>
    <API FlowName="Reservation"> 
        <Input>
            <ReserveItemInventory CheckInventory="Y" DemandType="RESERVED" ItemID="19998546" OrganizationCode="" QtyToBeCancelled="0" QtyToBeReserved="1" ReservationID="1000000000003" ShipNode="DC-W" UnitOfMeasure="EACH" xmlns="http://www.sterlingcommerce.com/documentation/YFS/reserveItemInventory/input"/>
        </Input>
    </API>
</MultiApi>
```

I have got the below XSLT but this fails since the value of xmlns attribute has "input" at the end. If I remove the xmlns attribute below XSL works as expected.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="MultiApi">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="API">
            <xsl:sort select="Input/ReserveItemInventory/@ItemID" data-type="number"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

I want the output to be as below

```
    <MultiApi TransIdKey="e5d6bd63-88cd-455f-8ab3-9510b5edb2b7" OrderId="" SoId="">
<API FlowName="Reservation"> 
    <Input>
        <ReserveItemInventory CheckInventory="Y" DemandType="RESERVED" ItemID="19998546" OrganizationCode="" QtyToBeCancelled="0" QtyToBeReserved="1" ReservationID="1000000000003" ShipNode="DC-W" UnitOfMeasure="EACH" xmlns="http://www.sterlingcommerce.com/documentation/YFS/reserveItemInventory/input"/>
    </Input>
</API>
<API FlowName="Reservation"> 
    <Input>
        <ReserveItemInventory CheckInventory="Y" DemandType="RESERVED" ItemID="19998548" OrganizationCode="" QtyToBeCancelled="0" QtyToBeReserved="1" ReservationID="1000000000003" ShipNode="DC-W" UnitOfMeasure="EACH" xmlns="http://www.sterlingcommerce.com/documentation/YFS/reserveItemInventory/input"/>
    </Input>
</API>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sort failed because the `ReserveItemInventory` element is in
`sterlingcommerce` namespace.

So in order to specify it in a sort key you have to specify this
namespace.

Make 2 changes:

- Add `xmlns:sc="http://www.sterlingcommerce.com/documentation/YFS/reserveItemInventory/input"`
  to the  `stylesheet` tag.
- Add `sc:` before `ReserveItemInventory` in the `sort` command.

In order to have `MultiApi` attributes copied to the output,
change `select` in `apply-templates` to `"@*|API"` (add `@*` to
specify attribute nodes and `|` as a separator).

The complete script is as follows (checked on xsltransform):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:sc="http://www.sterlingcommerce.com/documentation/YFS/reserveItemInventory/input">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="MultiApi">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|API">
        <xsl:sort select="Input/sc:ReserveItemInventory/@ItemID" data-type="number"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thanks for the response Valdi, changed XSL didnt work either

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:sc="http://www.sterlingcommerce.com/documentation/YFS/reserveItemInventory/input">
   ......

    <xsl:template match="MultiApi">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|API">
                <xsl:sort select="Input/sc:ReserveItemInventory/@ItemID" data-type="number"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: I suppose you missed any possible detail. The proposed solution definitely works.
The first output `API` element has `ItemID` = `19998546` and the second `19998548`, just as required. For a working example see http://xsltransform.net/gVhD8RY

Comment: Could you please post the XSL here?